# IF statement on submit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code and I'm trying to add some IF statements to the submit button, so it does not submit anything empty, or other than numbers and arithmetic operators, or shows error when operands are more than operators and vice versa, however it doesn't seem to work. [Here is the full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cherry-xnfif?file=/src/App.js).

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  if (inputValue.length === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult("You did not enter anything!")
  }
  if (inputValue === isNaN && inputValue !== validOperators) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult("only numbers!")
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    setResult(solution);
    setInputValue("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Protip: You're preventing default in all three blocks. Just do it once at the  top.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to show all relevant code here, and not direct us elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

isNan is not a value, it's a function. You need to call it.

I made the assumption that `validOperators` is an array or a string containing the valid operators.

If so, this is what you want:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
if (inputValue.length === 0) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResult("You did not enter anything!")
} if (isNaN(inputValue) || !validOperators.includes(inputValue)) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResult("only numbers (and valid operators)!")
} else {
  e.preventDefault();
  setResult(solution);
  setInputValue("");
 }
}
```